# Looking for a Qt-based library for 2-D plotting

Tags: qt, plotting

I want to develop an application in Qt that includes 2-D plotting of some data to be fetched. What I hope to find in such a library:

1. Multiple Y axis plots.
2. Zooming.
3. View data on mouse hover.
4. Pan.